# How to Create Identity field based on the row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Using SQL Server 2005

Table1

```
Code ID (identity field)

001 1
001 2
002 1
003 1
003 2
```

How to create a identity field based on the code.

Need Query Help

Comment: Do you really need identity? Are you maybe referring to primary key? It's not clear what you want to do.

Comment: Trying to maintain this structure with an ascending `ID` partitioned by `Code` will be a pain. Do you actually **need** this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like this:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
ADD NewColumn INT IDENTITY(1,1)
```

You can define the `seed` (starting value) as the first parameter, and the `step` (increments) as the second - so pick whatever makes sense to you; both seed=1 and step=1 seems to be the mostly used defaults.

The column will be added and populated with values when it's creatde.

Comment: This does not return the desired results though.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to implement `row_number()` which will increment the `id` value based on the number of `code` values that you have:

```
select code, id
from
(
  select code, 
    row_number() over(partition by code order by code) id
  from yourtable
) d;
```

Using `row_number()` will allow you to calculate the value when you query the data in your table. See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cab08/1).

If you want to update your table with this value, then you could use something like the following:

```
;with cte as
(
  select code, id, 
    row_number() over(partition by code order by code) rn
  from yourtable
) 
update cte
set id = rn;
```

See [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/62ee8/4).

Storing this value in your table will be difficult to maintain if you continue to add new rows for each `code`, it might be easier to implement the `row_number()` when you query the data.

Answer (score 0):

(On rereading your question, I see that your `id` column is not unique, so it could not be an identity column.)

To create an identity field that uses initial values from the `Code` column, you could:

```
-- Create an empty copy of your table
select  top 0 *
into    CopiedTable
from    YourTable;

-- Add an identity column
alter table CopiedTable add id int identity;

-- Copy the rows over, while initializing the identity column from Code
set identity_insert dbo.CopiedTable on

insert  dbo.CopiedTable
        (id, Code)
select  Code
,       Code
from    dbo.YourTable;

set identity_insert dbo.CopiedTable off

-- Drop the old table
drop table dbo.YourTable

-- Rename the copied table
exec sp_rename 'CopiedTable', 'YourTable'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [ROW_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

```
SELECT
  code, 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY code ORDER BY code) AS ID
FROM Table1
```

Answer (score -1):

get it from `count`

```
DECLARE @ID int = (
    SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 from test_1 WHERE [Code] = @CODE )
```